# Convert (format) clock time from H:MM to HH:MM

Tags: r, datetime, formatting

The time column is a mixed of `H:MM` and `HH:MM` as follows:

```
TIME
4:08
6:12
8:15
10:15
14:16
16:55
```

I want to format all the clock time to be in the `HH:MM` format as follows (i.e.: add zero when time is `H:MM`)

```
TIME
04:08
06:12
08:15
10:15
14:16
16:55
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `strptime`(or `as.POSIXct`) to read the date-time object and use `format`(or `strftime`) to extract time part.

```
format(strptime(df$TIME, "%H:%M"), "%H:%M")

# [1] "04:08" "06:12" "08:15" "10:15" "14:16" "16:55"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Input = ('TIME
4:08
6:12
8:15
10:15
14:16
16:55')

df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
df$TIME <- ifelse(nchar(df$TIME)==4, paste0("0", df$TIME), df$TIME)
df
   TIME
1 04:08
2 06:12
3 08:15
4 10:15
5 14:16
6 16:55
```

Answer (score 1):

Treating them like strings, one idea can be to use `paste0`, i.e.

```
d1$TIME[nchar(sub(':.*', '', d1$TIME)) == 1] <- paste0('0', d1$TIME[nchar(sub(':.*', '', d1$TIME)) == 1])
```

which gives,

> ```
>    TIME
> 1 04:08
> 2 06:12
> 3 08:15
> 4 10:15
> 5 14:16
> 6 16:55
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(TIME = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("10:15", 
"14:16", "16:55", "4:08", "6:12", "8:15"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One base R option is to use `regmatches` + `sprintf`, i.e.,

```
d <- `class<-`(do.call(rbind,with(df,regmatches(TIME,gregexpr("\\d+",TIME)))),"numeric")
df$TIME_new <- sprintf("%02i:%02i",d[,1],d[,2])
```

such that

```
> df
   TIME TIME_new
1  4:08    04:08
2  6:12    06:12
3  8:15    08:15
4 10:15    10:15
5 14:16    14:16
6 16:55    16:55
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you have a column with time, I am supposing you have a data frame. In this case, I put your data into a data frame and processed it with [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) transforming the times you wanted as two new columns: one being `character` and other being `time` as you did not specify the format you wanted the result. And a brief explain, `%R` is equivalent to `%H:%M`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

data.frame(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
           TIME = c("4:08", "6:12", "8:15", "10:15", "14:16", "16:55"),
           stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  as_tibble(.) %>% 
  mutate(TIME2 = format(strptime(TIME, "%R"), "%R"),
         TIME3 = as_hms(as.POSIXct(TIME, format = "%R")))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID TIME  TIME2 TIME3 
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <time>
#> 1     1 4:08  04:08 04:08 
#> 2     2 6:12  06:12 06:12 
#> 3     3 8:15  08:15 08:15 
#> 4     4 10:15 10:15 10:15 
#> 5     5 14:16 14:16 14:16 
#> 6     6 16:55 16:55 16:55
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>